# Google Charts Numeric Date

Tags: datetime, user-controls, slider, filtering, google-visualization

Error: column 0 is not numeric
Column 0 is my date column

```
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
...
// The variable date here is an epoch
var fullDate = new Date((parseInt(date)*1000));
r.push(new Date(fullDate.getYear(), fullDate.getMonth(), fullDate.getDay()));
// Logging r here yields: Mon Mar 06 113 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
...
var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
  'containerId': 'control1',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnLabel': 'Date',
       'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}
  }
});
```

I guess I need to find a way to make date numeric?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to instead of making date numeric, change the control type of the slider.

```
'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
```